# Spring REST CPU usage limiting among endpoints

Tags: spring, performance, rest, cpu-usage

I have a Spring REST API.
Let's say `/students/122/gpa` endpoint gives us GPA of the student with id=122

Let's  assume that we are pre-calculating all GPA data and write into an HashMap.

I don't want to query database for each request.

The problem is:

- GPA calculation process (let's sat `/calculate` endpoint) is a hard mathematical process consumes almost all CPU.
- When I trigger /calculate endpoint to refresh GPA HashMap, `/students/{studentId}/gpa` endpoint responses very slow as all the CPU is consumed by calculation.

Is there any way to under-prioritize some endppoints or some service tasks in Spring REST?

Comment: instead of a HashMap I would use a cache like CaffeineCache. This could be utilized to delegate the calculation to a separate cache pool at least.